# The destination param must be a connected account

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I use stripe library for payment . There is no exception without destination param but when I add this param this exception has occured "The destination param must be a connected account".

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_...";

Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chargeParams.put("amount", 1000);
chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
chargeParams.put("source", {TOKEN});
chargeParams.put("destination", {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID});

Charge.create(chargeParams);
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the API key, but you should still roll out a new secret test key by heading to your account settings: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys and clicking the "recycle" icon next to the key you want to replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a charge [through the platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform), the `destination` parameter must be set to the ID of the account for which you're accepting the payment.

In the example code on Stripe's site and in your question, you must replace `{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}` with the actual account ID. Account IDs are strings that start with `acct_` followed by random alphanumeric characters.

If your platform is using [standalone accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts), then you get the account ID in the `stripe_user_id` parameter in the [last step of the OAuth flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/reference#post-token-response).

If your platform is using [managed accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts), then you get the account ID when you [create an account](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_account), in the [`id`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#account_object-id) parameter.

Comment: Thank you for helping me Ywain . I created new account and I get account id . but now I get a different exception . it says "The 'destination' param cannot be set to your own account. when creating the debit" but I get other account's id .